# Angular2: How to make compiled (bundled) project to take data from JSON file?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

In my Angular2 project I take settings from JSON file and I would like it to take settings from JSON after compiling it for production.

I compiled the project with `ng build` command. And now I see that `angular-cli` inserted content of the JSON file into `main.bundle.js`. So the compiled project does not take data from JSON.

How to compile an Angular2 project so that it will take data from JSON file?

**update**
Here is a code of using JSON in the project:

```
export const CONFIG = require('../../assets/config/index.json');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*How do you use your JSON ? (please show some code).*

If you import it, it's normal that your JSON is bundled. If you want to use it as an external file so you can modify it on the fly and just reload the page with the new data, you should treat that JSON file as a simple web request and use `Http` to  `get` it. This way it won't be bundled.

Comment: Yes I want to use it as an external file. Thanks a lot!